# Camera is not being detected on Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, error, camera, webcam

I have a Macbook Pro (Retina) and recently my camera stopped working.

I didn't drop it or anything, it's just not being detected as a hardware.

When I try to see why, System Report shows me:

```
No video capture devices were found.
```

I don't have Apple support anymore and I can't find any comprehensive guide or tips for this kind of problem - I just found issues with the camera, but not itself not being detected.

I tried to reset NVRAM and other things such as Diagnose mode, which gave me this error code above:

```
4HDD/11/40000000:SATA(0,0)
```

But on subsequent runs of this diagnose mode gives me no error. I also think it's unlike SATA has to do with the camera, as it typically uses USB.

I'm kind of lost and I just want to take it to assistance only if there are no other options, since I need my computer to work.

Comment: Could the error with the SATA/HD be affecting the Camera, possible a corrupted hard drive?

Comment: It's actually a SSD, not HD. But I performed Disk Utility's First Aid and it didn't report anything wrong. If you have any tips on that sense, I would much appreciate @IronCraftMan .

Comment: ok. Have you tried reinstalling OS X?

Comment: No, I haven't, but do you really think that could fix this or are you just trying something different? Also, since I backup to TimeMachine, not sure that reinstaling / restoring time machine backup would change anything.

Comment: I'm not taking about restoring from time machine. Either re-download the OS X installer or use Recovery HD and just reinstall. My guess is that since you didn't have any physical damage, something may be wrong with the driver.

Comment: Right, but then I grab data back from time machine, but manually?
There should be a way to restore the driver in a more practical way.

Comment: you won't loose any of your data when reinstalling OS X.

Comment: It keeps all apps too? I guess it will only override /System, /Library, right? Thanks @IronCraftMan !

Comment: like I said, it won't delete any of your data. It's just like going from OS X 10.10 to 10.11, only you're just reinstalling the same version.

Comment: @IronCraftMan my issue was solved! I guess it was some of those steps (Diagnose, NVRAM/SMC reset, Disk Repair), and it "fixed itself". I was about to reinstall OS X today, but when I booted my Mac today, camera was ok (it flashed correctly when I ran software that needed it, in a meeting).
Anyways, thanks for the tip as it would probably solve my problem if those things didn't !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this problem, I would suggest going with [System Diagnose](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) + [NVRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) + [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) + [Disk repair](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201639).

And if none of those work, follow @IronCraftMan advice and proceed with [reinstalling OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) - you won't lose any data.

These steps worked for me.